# Stop Scrolling UIScrollView When Drawing its SubViews

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a task in that i am able to draw in subviews of UIScrollView. UIScrollView contains 3 Pages. Each Page contains many UIView as subviews in theses subviews i want to draw like writting but when i tocuh the view and start drawing i can do that because UIScrollView gets scrolled.How to stop scroll when writting time only.
 I searched lot for solution. I also used UIView's hitTest method but I am not succeed.Can you provide some suggestions to overcome this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some touchEvent handlers that you need to implement

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

In touchBegan event, you can set a logic to starting drawing after set

```
[yourScrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

once you done with drawing in touchEnded event you need to reset your scrollview.

```
[yourScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

P.S. I've not idea of working of my solution but you can try for this.